# Filter usernames in an array based on the highest score

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

We have a online mini game on our platform where users with similar names, such as: `Username`, `UserName` and `username` face each other. All this works perfectly, but now we are adding a leaderboard that takes your data out of a PHP array.

```
$positions = ConfrontationGame::getResults()->toArray();
```

Then the `$positions` variable is an array that has the following structure:

```
$positions => array {

    [
        'username' => 'Exampleusername',
        'score' => '74'
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'ExampleUsername',
        'score' => '14'
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'exampleusername',  // WINNER
        'score' => '96'
    ]

}
```

We use this array to create a table of positions where users with similar usernames (`EmapleUsername`,`Exampleusername` and `exampleusername`) who faced each other should only leave the one with the highest score, in this case the winner `exampleusername`

This is what we have:

```
$results_table = array_filter($positions, function($val, $key) {

        if($key === 'username' && in_array(strtolower($val), $positions)) {
            if($key === 'score') {
                // ...
                // What is done here?
            }        
        }

    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Comment: With `array_filter()`, the closure returns true or false to include in the set or not. `array_reduce()` takes an optional value such as an array that you pack with new information, which is eventually returned. If you want to interpret for instance to just a list of usernames, create a reducing function and pack your accumulator with just the usernames you want to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of looking at it.

```
<?php

$playersWithPosition = [[
    'username' => 'Exampleusername',
    'score' => '74'
],[
    'username' => 'ExampleUsername',
    'score' => '14'
],[
    'username' => 'exampleusername',  // WINNER
    'score' => '96'
]];

$leaderboard = static function(array $players) {
    $leaders = [];

    foreach($players as $player) {
        $leaders[(int) $player['score']] = $player['username'];
    }

    ksort($leaders);

    // Higher score is better, so reverse order.
    return array_values(array_reverse($leaders));
};

$leading = static function(array $players) use(&$leaderboard): ?string {
    return $leaderboard($players)[0] ?? null;
};

var_dump($leaderboard($playersWithPosition), $leading($playersWithPosition));
```

Which gives:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "exampleusername"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Exampleusername"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "ExampleUsername"
}

string(15) "exampleusername"
```

https://3v4l.org/ICGZf

Comment: Good, but this returns the 3 usernames and not just the username with the highest score

Comment: `$leaderboard[0]`

Comment: Based on the array that returns its function and that is similar to my example array, the winner is `exampleusername` in position [2] not `ExampleUsername` in position [0]

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán I modified it to return just the leader. You could do a reducer that simply compared the score, the question is how to keep reference with a sorting algorithm.

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán Then add `array_reverse()`, if a bigger score is better.

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartínezDurán - I made some improvements, I think it's easier to understand.